# django search form to query only when form is submitted

Tags: django, search

Here is my view

```
class SingleNewsView(ListView):
model = News
form_class = SearchForm
template_name = "single_news.html"



def get(self, request, pk, **kwargs):
    self.pk = pk

    self.pub_from = request.GET.get('pub_date_from',False)
    self.pub_to = request.GET.get('pub_date_to',False)
    self.crawlers = request.GET.get('crawler',False)

    print self.crawlers


    return super(SingleNewsView,self).get(request,pk, **kwargs)



def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super(SingleNewsView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["form"] = SearchForm#(self.request.GET)
    context["something"] = News.objects.filter(category_id=self.pk).filter(published_date__range=(self.pub_from,self.pub_to), crawler=self.crawlers)


    return context
```

Here when I enter into the page it doesnot show any news because to data are not provided. I want all the news to be displayed initially and when the user submit the form then only filter work. How can I do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `get_queryset()` method than the doing filtering in `get_context_data()`. You can add the method as below

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = News.objects.filter(category_id=self.pk)
    #you can change this to just support one of the pub_from or pub_to
    if self.pub_from and self.pub_to :
        qs = qs.filter(published_date__range=(self.pub_from,self.pub_to)
    if self.crawler:
        qs = qs.filter(crawler=self.crawlers)
```